# pathlib's relative_to doesn't accept walk_up parameter

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I'm using Python 3.10.12. I'm trying to walk back up a path to find a given folder and walk back down the tree again from that folder. Here's my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(__file__).relative_to('some-parent-path-i-know-exists', walk_up=True)
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: PurePath.relative_to() got an unexpected keyword argument 'walk_up'
```

According to pathlib's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to), I should be able to use the `walk_up` parameter to allow for the pattern to be matched even if the `Path` doesn't start with that pattern. My IDE even suggests `walk_up` as an auto-complete option for the call to the `relative_to()` function. That tells me the parameter does indeed exist.

I tried declaring `p` as a `PurePath`, but that didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You linked the Python3.12.1 documentation and as it says for `walk_up` parameter:

> Changed in version 3.12: The walk_up parameter was added (old behavior is the same as walk_up=False).

If you check [the same documentation for Python3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to), then you will see the `walk_up` parameter is not supported in that Python version. (I have checked the implementation of `PurePath` for Python3.10 and it's really not supported based on the implementation as well)

Comment: Ah you're right, thanks! I didn't expect this to be such a recent change. Then I guess i'll find another way to do this, as imposing 3.12 isn't an option in my case.